# Why parseInt(Infinity) returns NaN and parseFloat(Infinity) returns infinity?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, nan, infinity

What could be the reason to make these two functions behave differently for values infinity and -infinity. Does anyone ever find this inconsistency useful?

```
parseInt(Infinity); // NaN
parseFloat(Infinity); // Infinity
```

Comment: http://www.peterkroener.de/javascript-parseint-vs-parsefloat/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to that question is right in the specs for the two functions:

[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes a *string* parameter.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt returns NaN.

[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> parseFloat can also parse and return the value Infinity. You can use the isFinite function to determine if the result is a finite number (not Infinity, -Infinity, or NaN).

`parseInt` can't return `infinity` because `infinity` is not within JavaScript's integer range. whereas it is a valid within the floating point range.

As for *useful*? I can't say. In the domain that I work in, `NaN` means an error has happened and I don't believe I have *ever* used `infinity`

Comment: The `takes a string parameter` and `cannot be converted to a number,` is not necessarily the correct explanation.  `Number('Infinity')` is a Number that represents _Infinite_ and `parseFloat` also takes a string `parseFloat('Infinity')`. And `Infinity.toString();` will result into `"Infinity"`, so `parseInt(Infinity)`, will result into `parseInt("Infinity")`.

Comment: Infinity is not within JavaScript's integer range. Why? Numbers like 8888888888888888888888888888888888888888889889999999999999999999999 should be  infinity right?

Comment: @Devashish The maximum safe integer in  JS is `9007199254740991`, everything above is only floating point precision. [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: @t.niese sometimes behavior of JS is just unbelievable. Thanks :)

Comment: @Devashish it wouldn't be a difference in other languages. Non floating point numbers  like Integers cannot represent Infinite, so if you request an Integer you cannot get Infinite.

Comment: May be. I never found the value Infinity before JS.